# How to remove + sign from images name with space

Tags: html, laravel, url, imageurl

I have a system with registered users and user images . Some of user images are rename with the spaces Ex -: Prof Pic.jpeg

Now I tried to retrieve the user image it's shows + sign concatenate to the URL

```
https://my.space/photos/49/profile/Prof+Pic.jpeg
```

Expected Output is

```
https://my.space/photos/49/profile/Prof Pic.jpeg
```

Comment: `https://my.space/photos/49/profile/Prof Pic.jpeg` is an **invalid** URL (literal spaces are forbidden). `+` **means** "a space" in a URL. It doesn't make sense to do what you are asking.

Comment: @Quentin but the thing is i cannot view the images with the +

Comment: Have got any code that we could review?

Comment: @AliRasheed  src="https://my.space/{{ $data['receiverimage'] }}"

Comment: @Fed are you able to view with space?

Comment: @VikashPathak Yes

Comment: Then the server is somewhat broken, but you need to replace the `+` with ` %20` not a space. You should do that by fixing the code which generates the URL. You haven't shown us that. You need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: If this `/photos/49/profile/Prof+Pic.jpeg` is your url in database then it's wrong. You should only have the file name. Try something `{{ asset('/folder/of/picture/'.$filename) }}`

Answer (score 0):

do this if this is what you have in your database. depending on what you have in your db. ex. `Prof Pic.jpeg, profile/Prof Pic.jpeg`

```
https://my.space/photos/49/profile/Prof Pic.jpeg
```

you can remove it with adding

```
$getImgUrl=DB::table('table')->where('id',$request->input('id'))->first();

$url = $getImgUrl->imgurl;

$removeSpace=preg_replace('/\s/', '', $url);
```

you can now use `$removeSpace`